# The afternoon had been utterly still and airless, with a sultry brooding in its silence. --"sultry brooding"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

I have been reading a story by C.A. Smith, and I am not sure how the following can be understood:

> The afternoon had been utterly still and airless, with a sultry
> brooding in its silence.

For the context: A lone tramp is roaming the land. A few sentences earlier he was thínking of his wife and children, whom he had left.

Does it mean that the weather was inviting or enticing the person to think (brood)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a literary device called **personification** - the air is being ascribed a description that you would expect to be given only to a living thing. It is used as another way of describing something. In this case, the stillness of the air is given a 'heavy' or 'unpleasant' feeling by 'sultry brooding' because *brooding* has a dark and negative connotation. You could argue that this is connected to the character's feelings, but that is open to interpretation. Without context, I wouldn't read too much into it - it is a standard writing technique.

*Edit: A simple way to rewrite the sentence would be:*
The afternoon had been very still with no wind, giving it a hot and heavy feeling.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I probably was not precise enough - I understand the act of personification, I just cannot decipher what exactly "sultry brooding" means. If you could simply rephrase the sentence using more "common" words, that would help me a lot! I know "brooding" as an adjective but here it is a noun.

Comment: Brooding is usually an adjective but here it is the gerund (i.e. the act of brooding). The meaning is not so different.

Comment: Thanks, I think it is because "to brood" means basically to think about something (rather unpleasant), which I have problems to understand as "heavy" (when projected into your version).

Comment: Could I rephrase it like that: The afternoon had been utterly still and airless, and it seemed as if it was ruminating in that hot silence.

Comment: I'll be honest, that sounds a little strange to me. But it's not easy to explain why. I can't imagine the afternoon actively ruminating, but I can imagine the atmosphere as heavy and brooding.